# Chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -9

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I seem to have a setup issue with my Chrome driver for selenium. I really can't figure out the issue. Does anyone know what this is caused by / how to fix?

**Sample Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

**Error Raised**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /Users/antoinevandenheste/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64_m1/100.0.4896.60/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -9
```

What does `Status code was: -9` mean? I think it must be something related to some weird Mac OS M1 stuff as always.

**Note:** that I have tried `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Users/.../chromedriver` but it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Status code -9 usually means "killed".  You didn't "force quit" the app?

Comment: Nope literally just the code above is what I'm running

Comment: Did you download an M1 version of the Chrome driver?

Comment: yep :) @TimRoberts

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Did you figure this out yet?  Thanks.

Comment: my solution was to switch to puppeteer on Node.js instead lol @jbright

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will help everyone but it would have saved me tons of time.

I found that chromedriver didn't get killed and that kept raising the `Status code was: -9`.
When I did `driver.quit()` it killed the chromdriver process and was free to start another one.
Or just kill it from your task manager/activity monitor/cli.

I have not figured out why it doesn't allow more processes of chromedriver at the same time. Maybe someone can comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was allowing the unknown application to open in my Mac's security settings